# Using div as a viewport for floated elements inside of it

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a CSS/Angular only version of http://www.givainc.com/labs/ibutton_jquery_plugin.htm

My objective is to fully hide either the green or red piece by adjusting the left margin and only keeping the container wide enough for 1 to display.  I can't seem to stop the red piece from wrapping when I adjust the width of the slideToggle container.

http://jsfiddle.net/vGBgB/2/

```
<div class="slideToggle" ng-click="toggle" name="active" onlabel="Active" offlabel="Inactive" style="height: 34px; width: 115px;">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="stOn" style="width: 50px;">Active</span>
    <span class="stHandle">| | |</span>
    <span class="stOff">Inactive</span>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS (only posting because SO requires it)

```
.slideToggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.slideToggle > input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
.slideToggle > .stOff,
.slideToggle > .stOn {

    float: left;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 4px 10px 0;

    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #808080;
}
.stHandle {;
    float: left;
    min-width: 25px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdfdfd 0%,#ebebeb 99%);
    padding: 2px 1px 2px 0;

    border: 1px solid #8f8f8f;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #c6c6c6;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-align: center;
}
.slideToggle > .stOn {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -1px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8ab056 0%,#a2c46b 100%);
    border: 1px solid #88a75c;
    border-right: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.slideToggle > .stOff {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -1px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d4786a 0%,#e39080 100%);
    border: 1px solid #bd6e61;
    border-left: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
    .slideToggle > .stOff::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }
```

Comment: Did you consider working your HTML and CSS like this?  Modify the margin-left on .button-continer from -70px to 0px to "switch" the state.

All you have to do then is figure out how to toggle that margin with your checkbox, put css animations to it and make it look nice.

http://jsfiddle.net/D6EWF/

Comment: Demonstration fiddle of my above comment.  I just used some jquery to demonstrate it.  http://jsfiddle.net/D6EWF/1/

Comment: @Michael - I was hoping to accomplish this without adding another wrapper.  But if I need to I need to.  Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: The real advantage to re-organizing your HTML as I have suggested is simply because it's more natural.  You want to make a sliding element, so why not just make it slide?  Using overflow:hidden and specific widths and heights you have full control over what is seen and what is not seen, and probably even a little less code overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to adjust your HTML layout.  Since we are trying to create a sliding effect, why not set up your HTML to actually slide your button content.  Use `overflow: hidden;` to hide any extra you don't need.  This also allows you to set very specific widths and heights to assist in consistency.

We'll use a container to specify the total width and height of your button plus an active or inactive span.  Then we'll use another container that holds the total width of all 3 spans.  Then all we have to do is add `margin-left:` to the second container to "slide" it within the first container.  `Overflow:hidden;` is our real champion here.

Here is a JSFiddle in which I have included some sample jquery to demonstrate that it works.  You will need to adapt the code to match your checkbox requirement and such.  Feel free to use the jquery if you decide that jquery is a better solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/D6EWF/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="button-container" class="">
        <span class="red">Inactive</span>
        <span id="button" class="button"> | | | </span>
        <span class="green">Active</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#button-container {
    width: 170px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.active {
    margin-left: -70px;
}

.red, .button, .green { 
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.red, .green {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.button {
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: why you use display: block with  float: left??? Float already give to elemet blocks property

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<span class="switcher">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1">
        <label for="chk1">
            <span class="on">ON</span>
            <span class="btn">| | |</span>
            <span class="off">OF</span>
        </label>
    </span>
```

CSS

```
.switcher{
            width: 100px;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: block;
            border: 1px #000 solid;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        .switcher input[type="checkbox"]{
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        .switcher input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label{margin-left:0;}
        .switcher label{
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 170%;
            font:14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-left: -70%;
        }
        .switcher label .on,
        .switcher label .off{
            float: left;
            width: 40%;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            background: rgb(169,219,128);
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2E5ZGI4MCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiM5NmM1NmYiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,219,128,1) 0%, rgba(150,197,111,1) 100%);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(169,219,128,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(150,197,111,1)));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,219,128,1) 0%,rgba(150,197,111,1) 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,219,128,1) 0%,rgba(150,197,111,1) 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,219,128,1) 0%,rgba(150,197,111,1) 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(169,219,128,1) 0%,rgba(150,197,111,1) 100%);
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
            border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
        }
        .switcher label .off{
            background: rgb(255,48,25);
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,48,25,1) 0%, rgba(207,4,4,1) 100%);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,48,25,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(207,4,4,1)));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,48,25,1) 0%,rgba(207,4,4,1) 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,48,25,1) 0%,rgba(207,4,4,1) 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,48,25,1) 0%,rgba(207,4,4,1) 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,48,25,1) 0%,rgba(207,4,4,1) 100%);
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
            border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
        }
        .switcher label .btn{
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            width: 22%;
            margin: 0 -1%;
            position: relative;
            background: rgb(238,238,238);
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(238,238,238,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(238,238,238,1)));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
```

Comment: No description of what you changed?

Comment: Checkbox occupies the entire area of ​​the button. Label has a greater width than the button and moves when the checkbox marked